# How to add different values to unique keys in Realm?

Tags: java, android, json, realm

I'm unable to wrap my head around a problem I'm facing.

I have various json keys, let's say:
Name, grades, skills.

Now for each name, name, there can be multiple grades and skills, so the json could be like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1"
        "age": "age1"
        "skills": "skills1"
    },
    {
        "name": "name1"
        "age": "age2"
        "skills": "skills2"
    },
    {
        "name": "name1"
        "age": "age3"
        "skills": "skills3"
    }
]
```

Notice how name isn't changing, but skills and age are. In this case, how do I map all the different ages and skills to that one single name? I don't know the number of unique names in advance.

Let me know if I've missed out any details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "name1",
    "age"  : ["age1","age2","age3"],
    "skills" : ["skills","skill2"]
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2",
    "age"  : ["age1","age2","age3"],
    "skills" : ["skills","skill2"]
  }
]
```